# In Phantomjs How can I skip some resource from being cached if disk cache is enabled?

Tags: phantomjs, browser-cache, http-caching

In order to save bandwidth we have enabled disk cache for out phantomjs instances. What we need to be able to do is to skip using cache for particular files (could be based on URL).

In other words we want the cache mechanism to be active but we want to be able to check each request and decide if we want to skip cache and make direct call on a URL basis.

Is it for instance possible to remove all cache headers when we receive a resource?

I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Depending on the scale of your need, you might consider writing a custom proxy server to handle the response headers in whatever way you'd like.  As a bonus, you could cache on the proxy instead of on PhantomJS, enabling a shared cache for several PhantomJS instances.

Comment: Hi Brad, That is not an option for us. We need to be able to do that per resource and through phantomjs.  I have also tried requestData.setHeader('Cache-Control','no-store'); under onResourceRequested with no avail.

Comment: I was suggesting that your custom proxy could customize the headers on a per-resource basis, or in any way you like.

Comment: Are you saying that this is not possible from within phantomjs?

Comment: Not at all, I'm just saying that it's a possible solution depending on your specific requirements.  I couldn't tell you about PhantomJS with certainty.  I use it but only at a surface level for running screen shots.  Nothing complex.

Comment: You can probably go ahead and delete the cache files on disk, but the challenge would be identifying the correct files. Also, I don't know if PhantomJS actually uses the disk-cache during a single process execution or if it also preserves the cache in-memory.

Comment: Is there anyway we can locate those files on the disk? The problem is the file names on disk look like randomly generated names. Is there anyway we can related those files to their actual url?